# PC display is blinking - Turning off and on again in intervals

Tags: graphics-card, display, power-supply, desktop-computer, external-display

Let me start by saying this is something that has been happening since I first built my PC a couple of years ago and it's been a real mystery to me since then... Let me explain why.

### The issue

My PC monitor blinks at random times. The screen starts turning ON and OFF again in approximately two seconds of OFF intervals, with less than one second ON time in between. This continues endlessly and usually gets resolved after I remove the connection cable and re-insert it, or when I turn the monitor OFF and ON again.

I have recorded two videos to better demonstrate the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dX4OQ8cBygc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deWqW5J47hY

#### Under which circumstances it happens?

The issue appears randomly and in infrequent times. Doesn't matter if the PC is idle or under stress and happens in any screen, even on the BIOS startup screen. Sometimes appears multiple times in a single day and sometimes takes a couple of days to re-appear.

### What I have tried

There's really few things I haven't tried already...

- I have replaced `CPU`, `CPU cooler fan`, `PSU`, `GPU`, `SSD`, `RAM` and `Motherboard` (kept same model though). I have pretty much replaced the whole computer except from the PC case.
- I have tried different HDMI cables (happens on Display Port too)
- I have tried on my 4K TV as well as on my Full HD monitor, happens on both
- I have tried on Windows and on Linux (Ubuntu), happens on both

### Current setup

All components are new and nothing has been overclocked.

- PSU: `Corsair RMX White Series (2018), RM850x, 850 Watt`
- CPU: `Intel Core i7-9700K`
- GPU: `GIGABYTE AORUS GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER 8GB`
- CPU Cooler: `Noctua NH-D15 chromax.Black, Dual-Tower CPU Cooler (140mm, Black)`
- SSD: `Samsung 970 EVO Plus Series`
- RAM: `Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 DRAM 3200MHz`
- Motherboard: `MSI MPG Z390 Gaming Edge AC`
- PC Case: `Fractal Design Meshify C`

### Questions

What could be the root cause of this issue and what else can I try to narrow it down? Does this seem like an electrical short circuit? And if so, how can I verify or detect its source?

I would appreciate any help...

Comment: Does the issue occur only with the GeForce RTX 2060 or does it also happen with the integrated graphics, if you plug a monitor into it? Also, have you tried keeping multiple monitors plugged in and observing if the blinking occurs on both, and at the same time?

Comment: I have switched 3 graphic cards since I first built the PC. It was occurring with all three of them. I’m not sure I have tried what you are suggesting... Maybe I have but don’t remember... I’ll give it a go though see what happens

Comment: You could try using an UPS, to see if this is caused by an electric power surge.

Comment: You said you tried two displays, but did you try another power cord? Sometimes it happened that the power connector on the back of the monitor slipped out a bit.

Comment: Have you tried checking for an electrical problem?

Comment: @ManSamVampire Interestingly, the issue reoccurred today and I immediately changed  the display settings to be duplicated to my TV. As soon as I did that the issue disappeared. I think this pretty much excludes cables as the root cause... I also had it in duplicate mode for few days and issue never appeared during that time. Maybe it was a coincidence maybe not... I would need more time to verify. Does this tell you anything...?

Comment: @harrymc What would be the process of checking for electrical issues?

Comment: Protect the computer with a UPS or at least a surge protector and see if it stops happening.

Comment: @ManSamVampire So removed the GPU and tried with the integrated card. After 3 days issue reoccurred. I’ve never seen it happen on both monitors at the same time. This could just be a cooncidence though, as I don’t use both monitors at the same time for prolonged times. I’ll try to test it out though. I have also ordered a “premium” cable to make 100% sure it’s not a cable issue. I’ll report back!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried any other devices or computers with your monitor and TV? Have you tried your computer at any other place?

Problem looks and feels odd, like monitor/TV failure or GPU failure. But since you have changed GPU and tried with different displays those should be OK. You have tried different cables as well.

Another thing to look into is overclocking. Have you checked all the settings that there is no overclocking for CPU, RAM and GPU?

And at last but not least, is it possible to measure voltage between PC and monitor/TV? They might be plugged into different phases and there might be some difference in voltage, that might interfere. If they are plugged into the same wall outlet via extension wire, then this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks! My Playstation was connected to my TV and the monitor has been used with a laptop for work. In both cases no problem at all... The monitor and PC are not connected in the same power outlet, but the TV and PC are on the same outlet extension. When I go into Bios, overclocking is not enabled and I have not done anything to overclock anything... Everything is straight out of the box. Please let me know if you have any suggestions that I should try out...

Comment: What's interesting is the temporary fix. Disconnecting the cable and reconnecting it. That works almost every single time... GPU was my very first thought too and it was one of the things I replaced first to mitigate the issue. Then I slowly ended up replacing everything and issue still persists. I'll try connecting the monitor and PC in the same extension outlet see if it makes any difference...

Comment: Tried with both PC and monitor on the same power extension to no avail...

Comment: I see your CPU is Core-i7, which means it should have built-in Intel GPU. Could you try connecting internal GPU output to the monitor instead of RTX 2060? There should be a separate DisplayPort socket on the motherboard.

Comment: I could give it a try! Although I have switched a total of 3 different GPUs, so I can't see how it could be due to the GPU... It's been two days now without having the issue. That is what makes it hard to debug as well... I can try things but then needs some time to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, it seems the issue has been resolved. The problem was caused by the Display Port and HDMI cables. Although I had tried different cables, they were all the "cheap" ones that came with my devices. I thought the chances of having the same issue with different cables was very slim, so I excluded the cables as the potential cause.

I bought a premium Display Port cable and the issue hasn't appeared for more than a month now. I can't believe the monitor came with such a cheaply made cable that actually doesn't work.

So for anyone out there, don't trust the cables that come with your devices. Also, big thanks to everyone that helped me to narrow down the root cause.